# Stop a batch file completely when in a "call :loop"

Tags: windows, batch-file

How does one stop a batch file completely when in a called loop?

`exit /b` merely quits the :label loop, not the entire batch file, while bare `exit` exits the batchfile *and* the parent CMD shell, which is not desired.

```
@echo off
call :check_ntauth

REM if check fails, the next lines should not execute
echo. ...About to "rmdir /q/s %temp%\*"
goto :eof

:check_ntauth
  if not `whoami` == "nt authority\system" goto :not_sys_account
  goto :eof

:not_sys_account
  echo. &echo. Error: must be run as "nt authority\system" user. &echo.
  exit /b
  echo. As desired, this line is never executed.
```

results:

```
d:\temp>whoami
mydomain\matt

d:\temp>break-loop-test.bat

 Error: must be run as "nt authority\system" user.

 ...About to "rmdir /q/s d:\temp\systmp\*"     <--- shouldn't be seen!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `ERRORLEVEL` from the `:not_sys_account` subroutine and use it as a return value. The main procedure can check this and change its behavior:

```
@echo off
call :check_ntauth

REM if check fails, the next lines should not execute
if errorlevel 1 goto :eof
echo. ...About to "rmdir /q/s %temp%\*"
goto :eof

:check_ntauth
  if not `whoami` == "nt authority\system" goto :not_sys_account
  goto :eof

:not_sys_account
  echo. &echo. Error: must be run as "nt authority\system" user. &echo.
  exit /b 1
  echo. As desired, this line is never executed.
```

The diff from the original code is that `exit /b 1` now specifies an `ERRORLEVEL` and the check `if errorlevel 1 goto :eof` terminates the script if the `ERRORLEVEL` is set.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop it with a syntax error.

```
:not_sys_account
    echo Error: ....
    call :HALT

:HALT
call :__halt 2>nul
:__halt
()
```

The HALT function stops the batch file, it uses itself a second function so it can supress the output of the syntax error by redirection to nul

Comment: Superb! I'll have to give this a try next time I need it. I usually set a variable a the beginning like: **`fatalError=0`**, then set it to **`fatalError=1`** on an error, and check the value on return from :calls.

Comment: I like this, thanks for the idea. I ended up giving Jon the nod though because that approach feels cleaner to me for something that will be maintained in future by someone else.